# Printing integer values in socket programming with C language

Tags: c

I am working with Client and Server application with Linux in C language.
I can send answer to client like : `write(client_sock ,"HELLO",100)`, but I want to send also integers like I do with `printf("INTEGER A EQUALS TO %d",A);`

I mean I need to send also integer values with write() function.

In other words how can I send message like "Integer A equals to 5" to client with write() function?

Comment: You should think carefully about whether this is really what you want to do. Sending multi-byte data (e.g. integers) is complicated by architecture-specific details like integer size and byte ordering. The simplest approach is to format a string locally (e.g. with `snprintf`) and send that string to the remote side. If the remote side wishes to extract the integer, they can parse the string. Doing anything else requires careful definition of a protocol with a particular size and byte order for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to write the string in a buffer.

```
char msg[100];

// Clearing the message buffer 
memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));

// This writes the string in the msg buffer
sprintf(msg, "INTEGER A EQUALS TO %d", A); 

// Send the message
write(client_sock, msg, 100);
```

Comment: Defining the buffer with 1024 elements, sending 100 where actually less then 50 are needed...?

Comment: @alk: Worse than that, undefined behaviour because most of the 100 bytes sent have indeterminate value, never having been initialized.

Comment: @ alk Who cares about the size of the buffer. This is not an error.

Comment: @rici The fact that 100 bytes are sent is not a problem, and probably a requirement if the other side expects and read 100 bytes. This is the reason I left the write instruction as in the question. The `'\0'` is include in the msg. This is important.

Comment: @chmike: Nonetheless, the contents of an uninitialized buffer are indeterminate, and use of indeterminate values in automatic variables is undefined behaviour. (In other words, the buffer should at least be initialized.)

Comment: I agree. It is not a good practice, because it reveals prior content of the stack. Ok I'll fix the code. But I'll leave the 100 because otherwise the user's code might not work anymore.